# How to create A Z index with pagination (links) php or js

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a A Z index with php and also create each link to a inner page

i have this code:

```
for($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {  
$letter = chr($i);  
echo '<a href="index.php?letter='.$letter.'">'.$letter.'</a> | ';  }
```

but i read here each code in ascii and i dont see how to create the proper page https://www.codigosascii.com i have something wrong? i dont have any problem in use js if is necessary

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Creating/coding `index.php`?

Comment: What is the problem? Your code looks good. I am sure you will see hyperlinked A B C etc. If you want to act upon it in index.php, use $_GET["letter"] to see how it was called.

Comment: By the way, you can iterate all letters by using `foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $letter) {}`.